# jQuery call plugin method from inside callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a boilerplate plugin design which looks like this,

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = "test",
        defaults = {};

    function test( element, options ) {
        this.init();
    }

    test.prototype = {   
        init: function() {}
    }

    $.fn.test = function(opt) {
        // slice arguments to leave only arguments after function name
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return this.each(function() {
            var item = $(this), instance = item.data('test');
            if(!instance) {
                // create plugin instance and save it in data
                item.data('test', new test(this, opt));
            } else {
                // if instance already created call method
                if(typeof opt === 'string') {
                    instance[opt].apply(instance, args);
                }
            }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Now say i have two `<div>` with same class `container`.

And now i would call my `test` plugin on these divs like so,

```
$(".container").test({
    onSomething: function(){

    }
});
```

Now when function `onSomething` is called from inside my plugin how can i call that plugin public methods referring to the instance `onSomething` function was called from?

For example something happened with the *first* `container` div and `onSomething` function was called for only *first* `container` div.

To make it a bit more clear I have tried to pass `this` instance to the `onSomething` function, that way i expose **all** plugin data and then i can do something like,

```
onSomething(instance){
   instance.someMethod();
   instance.init();
   //or anything i want
}
```

To me me it looks quite wrong so there must be a better way... or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well im not sure if it is the best idea, but you could pass the current object as a parameter. Let's say `onSomething : function(obj) { }
So whenever "onSomething" is called by the plugin, you can call it like this: "onSomething(this)" and then refer to the object as`object`
Lets give a specific example.

```
var plugin = function (opts) {
 this.onSomething = opts.onSomething;
 this.staticProperty = 'HELLO WORLD';
 this.init = function() {
  //Whatever and lets pretend you want your callback right here.
  this.onSomething(this);
 }
}
var test = new Plugin({onSomething: function(object) { alert(object.staticProperty) });
test.init(); // Alerts HELLO WORLD
```

Hope this helps, tell me if its not clear enough.

Oh wait, thats what you did.

Comment: Yeah i did the same thing you did here :)